# Is this language context-free? $\Sigma$ = {a,b,#} L = {x1#x2#...#xk : k$\geq$2, every $x_i \in$ {a,b}* and xi $\neq$ xj for every pair i $\neq$ j}

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free, pumping-lemma

Is this language context-free? $\Sigma$ = {a,b,#}, L = {x1#x2#...#xk : k$\geq$2, every $x_i \in$ {a,b}* and xi $\neq$ xj for every pair i $\neq$ j} I think it is not, because the PDA can't memorize every word to be unequal to every other word.

Comment: What have you tried towards _proving_ your claim? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!